# How can I include a .js file to all jsp pages of my project without editing it?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

The file should be included to all jsp pages dynamically during run time

Comment: are you including any jsp file from your desire jsp ?

Comment: no , Need to load JS on run time

Comment: then there were no change to append Js into JSP, it's req. edit existing code. as per my consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<jsp-config>
   <jsp-property-group>     
     <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
     <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
     <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
     <is-xml>false</is-xml>
     <include-prelude>/javascript.jsp</include-prelude>
   </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>
```

And include your JS file in javascript.jsp. I haven't tried if directly telling include-prelude to include the JS actually works or not, worth a try.